# Responsive row-based grid layout

Tags: css

I built a website which has a page with a grid of images arranged in rows. 
For illustration you can find it [here](https://www.morethangraffiti.com/overview) but in principle it looks like this:

[image: Flexible arrangement of images]

1. The row height is flexibel.
2. The row fills the screen width (with margin).
3. The number of images per row is not fixed and needs to change depending on the window size.
4. The images’ dimension is arbitrary.

At the moment I am doing all the calculations in js / jQuery such that the row height is in between a minimum and a maximum height and then I distribute the images accordingly among the rows, creating or deleting new rows if necessary. On a resize event of the browser I recalculate the values and adjust the image dimensions and, if necessary, move pictures from one row to another.

While this works on a desktop screen I want to switch to a responsive design that also works on small (e.g. mobile) screens as well and does not have to rely as heavy on js /jQuery as it does at the moment.

I already found the bootstrap and Foundation frameworks but all of them use a fixed number of total columns which would not work here.

Is there a way to realize this, maybe even with using only CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about `flexbox`? for instance you can make a container with items width based on the container:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; margin: 10px; display: flex;">

<div class="item" style="background-color: red; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; flex: 1;">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>This is a lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>

<div class="item" style="background-color: red; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; flex: 1;">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>This is a lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>

<div class="item" style="background-color: red; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; flex: 1;">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>This is a lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>

<div class="item" style="background-color: red; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; flex: 1;">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>This is a lorem ipsum text</p>
</div>


</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9yhds8b/

Learn more about it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried doing something with it. But there I still would have to do all the calculations to determine the “perfect” image size off all images and update the individual image widths and heights. and if there are too many or little images in a row, I would have to rearrange them by hand, too. Or, maybe, did I overlook something?

Comment: Hmm not sure indeed, I think I have read your quesiton wrong. I used this one time before, but I was using fixed images that time. So, all images were the same size..

Comment: Pity though, I would have liked such a simple solution ;)